# ASP.NET MVC create a view with a model class containing complex objects

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to create a view (with Razor engine) by mapping the model class to `Person` class through the Add View option in Visual Studio 2013.

When it creates a view it only creates Age, Gender, Name fields. However, I need a view which would list down all the properties in each class; i.e. I need a view which contains the following fields: `Age`, `Name`, `Gender`, `EmployerName`, `Salary`, `City`, `State`, and `Country`.

I have a a class similar to this:

```
public class Person
{
    public int Age { get; set }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public JobDetails JobDetailsInfo { get; set; }
    public Address AddressInfo { get; set; }
}

public class JobDetails 
{
    public string EmployerName { get; set; }
    public string Designation { get; set; }
    public int Salary { get; set; }
}

public class Address 
{
    public string City { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public int Country { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: When you say `the IDE` do you mean Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1):

As your relationships are 1:1, this is pretty straight-forward.
You'll have to manually edit the view. Assuming the `Model` is of type `Person`, here's an example row:

```
<tr>
    <td>@Model.Age</td>
    <td>@Model.Name</td>
    <td>@Model.Gender</td>
    <td>@Model.JobDetailsInfo.EmployerName</td>
    <td>@Model.JobDetailsInfo.Salary</td>
    <td>@Model.AddressInfo.City</td>
    <td>@Model.AddressInfo.State</td>
    <td>@Model.AddressInfo.Country</td>
</tr>
```

This will work as long as you have that simple relationship, but if what you've shown does not correctly represent any normalisation you've applied to the data structure, this will fall flat on its face.

Comment: Thanks Eraph..The view may contain collections of objects also.. Hence i have used Partial views .all these partial views are called from one parent view(a nother cshtml) using @Html.Partial..Now i want the view to show up default data whenever it comes up.Also, i want to capture the values from the view again by reading each field(assuming user has changed some fields)..any pointers towards achieving both the behaviors while using partial views

Comment: My suggestion would be to have a run through the tutorials, it'll cover the majority of what you're trying to achieve and give you a solid understanding of how MVC development works.  http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started

Answer (score 0):

create the view manually or use inheritence...something like

```
public class jobdetails : person 
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
I slightly changed my class structure and i created partial views for commondata,jobdetails and address and used them in my main view using @Html.Partial. I was able to pass default data by creating an object instance and loading some default values and passed the entire object to the view  .The catch here is the model class which is bind to the Parent view must conatin all properties which are used for creating partial views. Pls see below

   Controller method: 
//Assign all properties for person object here
return View("ViewName", "PersonObject");

.cshtml:
@Html.Partial("ViewPath",Model.Data)
@Html.Partial("ViewPath",Model.JobDetailsInfo )
@Html.Partial("ViewPath",Model.AddressInfo )


    public class Person
    { 
    public CommonData Data
    public JobDetails JobDetailsInfo { get; set; }
    public Address AddressInfo { get; set; }
    }

    public class CommonData
    {
     public int Age { get; set }
      public string Gender { get; set; }
      public string Name { get; set; }

    }

    public class JobDetails 
    {
        public string EmployerName { get; set; }
        public string Designation { get; set; }
        public int Salary { get; set; }
    }

    public class Address 
    {
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string State { get; set; }
        public int Country { get; set; }
    }
```